# How to compile with "-lusb"

Tags: c, linux

How do I compile the code below. They say "compile with -lusb", but I don't know how to do that.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>

main(){

    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;
    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();
    
    for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next){
            printf("Trying device %s/%s\n", bus->dirname, dev->filename);
            printf("\tID_VENDOR = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor);
            printf("\tID_PRODUCT = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idProduct);
        }
}
```

Comment: `They say "compile with -lusb".` Actually library isn't necessary for successful compilation, but header files are required. Library is required for successful linkage.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but you should use `int main(void)` rather than `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully compile and run your program.

First, there are three things you should know about `-lusb`.

- The `-` means it's an option to the compiler, in my case I use `gcc`.
- The `l` that prefixes `usb` means it is an **external** library we are including in our compilation of this program.
- The `usb` is the library name, and is associated with the `#include <usb.h>` (usb is the usb.h excluding its suffix)

The command I used:

```
gcc  usb.c -o usb -lusb
```

I am using `gcc 4.7.3` and `libusb 1.0.18`

Edit: Correctly specify -lusb *after* the source code file.

Comment: I will get linkage error, when I launch your command. I believe you should replace something.

Comment: i still have a problem when i compile. it say (libusb.h: No such file or directory). I have already download libusb as follow "sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev" can you give me any suggestion. @NuclearPeon

Comment: @user3513915, try `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev`.

Comment: @user3513915, or explicitly specify path `-I/usr/include/libusb-1.0`.

Comment: @Gluttton can you elaborate? What do you believe I should replace? @user3513915 I use gentoo; the libusb package includes dev files so you are probably missing the package that Gluttton mentioned. Follow his instructions and if that fails, call `sudo find /usr -name 'libusb*'` and ensure you have the headers installed.

Comment: I believe the `-lusb` argument has to *follow* the `usb.c` argument, so that unresolved symbols in `usb.c` (actually in the generated `usb.o`) can be resolved by the `libusb` library. Incidentally, there's no *necessary* correlation between the `<usb.h>` header name and the `-lusb` library name; it's a convention.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-lusb` to your gcc command:

```
gcc -Wall -o usb usb.c -lusb
```

Comment: What are you talking about - there is no order to the command. It could just as easily be `gcc usb.c -Wall -lusb -o usb`.

Comment: It seems the person you were talking to deleted their comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There are absolutely an order to it. For static libraries, the containing object files will be discarded if nothing on the command line needs anything from the archives so far. For shared libraries, linux distros as of a few years now run the linker with the --as-needed flag, which will also discard shared libraries in much the same way.

Comment: Point well taken, but the answer was given in the context of the question posed here with a single lib and no further lib dependencies. For the case where you are dealing with standard so libraries which have no explicit library dependencies themselves, it doesn't matter where the `-l<libname>` appears on the command line. If the library you want in turn, depends on additional libraries, the yes it matters that the dependencies are listed after the library your want. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Really? it builds fine here without any problem. Do you have libusb installed? At the command prompt try `find /usr/include/usb.h` Is it there? Check your library path. Do you have `libusb.so`?

Comment: Also, if you are still having problems compiling the code, edit your question and post the exact gcc command you are using **and** the exact output your get. Folks here are happy to help, but can't see your screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -Wall -g -lusb prog.c -o prog
```